# error when I use query with like in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-like

there are an error when i use like in my query, the error when i use quotation (') only 
this my code

```
zz = "SELECT * from users where userid Like  N'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
Dim cmdz As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(zz, myConnection2)
zr = cmdz.ExecuteReader
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
If zr.HasRows Then
    While zr.Read
        Dim rowall As String() = New String() {zr("customer").ToString, zr("Management").ToString, zr("block").ToString, zr("Customerid").ToString}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowall)
    End While
    DataGridView1.Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: What is the error?  The query, although prone to SQL injection, looks logically correct.

Comment: see the tag comment: DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Use [facebook-like] for the Facebook Like functionality. Use [sql-like] for the SQL reserved keyword LIKE.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen the error when i write firist char in textbox  '  and press btn it give msg (Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters which will convert your input into valid sql query (so you don't have to escape single quotes)

```
zz = "SELECT * from users where userid Like  N'%' + @userId +'%'"
Dim cmdz As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(zz, myConnection2)
cmdz.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: it gave error when i use N'%' + @userId +'%'"  i think it's not correct put (userId)  between  + +

Comment: @hishamahmed so, what's the error? "it gave error" isn't very specific...

Comment: when i write first letter ' in textbox and press btn it gives  error msg (Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.) it means the qoutation identify as a part of query not as varchar to search it in the dbs

Comment: @hishamahmed in that case, replace one single quote with two single quotes. I have edited my answer

Comment: it works good also works with out Replace("'", "''"), thanks Nino